# Ember Simple Auth change path /token

Tags: ember.js

I'm use Ember Simple Auth

How can I change path `/token` if I used `OAuth2PasswordGrant` and `OAuth2Bearer`?

My App adapter:

```
export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {
    authorizer: 'authorizer:oauth2'
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`/token` path is default value of `serverTokenEndpoint` property of *OAuth2PasswordGrantAuthenticator* class. You can change it by using `.set('serverTokenEndpoint, '/yourTokenURL')` function on *OAuth2PasswordGrantAuthenticator* instance.

Comment: Thanks, it's work! I change it on app authenticator: 
`export default OAuth2PasswordGrant.extend({
 serverTokenEndpoint: '/api/login'
});`